# Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in PHP 7.4

Tags: php

I recently upgraded by server to PHP 7.4 and I've been updating my coding on some pages.  I keep getting the following error in my error logs and I've been racking my brain trying to figure out what's causing it:

PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

I'm passing the ID on a URL in the first line of code below and then the error is being generated in the second line on the profile.php page.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
print "<a href=\"profile.php?id=$row[id]-$row[model_stem]-stem-number-$row[serial]\" target=\"_blank\">Profile</a>";
```

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM registration WHERE `id`='".$_REQUEST['id']."' LIMIT 1") or die (mysqli_error($link));
```

Comment: please, before you do anything else upgrade to parasitised queries such as PDO as suggested in the comment

Answer (score 0):

In your print statement, you need to quote the array indices, like this:

```
<?php
print '<a href="profile.php?id='.$row['id'].'-'.$row['model_stem'].'-stem-number-'.$row['serial'].'" target="_blank">Profile</a>';
```

Comment: Usage of mysqli is deprecated, please use PDO instead. If you insist in using mysqli, please use mysqli_real_escape_string when executing queries in the fashion you did (by concatenating values in the query) to avoid SQL injection. 

As for your error, the answer from @Rob should be fine